# c# code formatting with BlogEngine.Net

Tags: c#, blogs, blogengine.net

I am new to blogging and started using BlogEngine.Net. Default [code:c#] [/code] formatting doesn't work with all the skins.

For example, if I use inove theme, it doesn't format the code with the above whereas if I use ProfessionalLight theme, it formats the c# code.

I will be posting lot of code in my blogs from now on and would love to have clear understanding about it.

People have discussed about using Windows Live Writer tool. Which is the best formatter for C# code. Can someone share their experience in C# code formatting in blogs.

Cheers,

Happy coder

Comment: This does not feel exactly as a programming question. Anyway; I have tweaked my own theme to use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). I guess there are extensions that will enable SyntaxHighlighter in a more automatic fashion for you.

Comment: @Fredrik - Can I use it with BlogEngine.Net. Does it require lot of work to get it going?

Comment: it's rather easy. You include a few script and stylesheet file references in the header and then use pre block with appropriate class attributes for the code. Check the website for SyntaxHighlighter, there is clear information there.

Comment: @Fredrik - Thanks mate for your help. I have started usind WLW and added few really good plugins. I will definitely try your way soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New BlogEngine 2.0 comes with real nice code formatting. Use that guys